# convert objects to JSON and send via jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've 1 object:

```
var myobject = {first: 1, second: {test: 90}, third: [10, 20]};
```

and I want to send it as `JSON` string via `jQuery ajax`.

How can I do it? (i test `JSON.stringify()`, but it doesn't work in IE)

Thanks.

Comment: You can also make it work in IE by including a java script from here:
http://www.json.org/js.html It is a commonly used approach.

Comment: Include this js file [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) Then you will get the JSON.stringify() method.

Comment: see this question: [serializing to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: for cross browser support add this javascript file in your html: [https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) it should provide JSON.stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify your `myobject` as the `data` parameter to the jQuery `.ajax()` method, it will automatically convert it to a query string, which I believe is what you want.

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: /* ... */,
    data: myobject,
    /* other settings/callbacks */
})
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> data
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass your object to the 'data' parameter of the `ajax` function -

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: myobject ,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```